# Windows Server 2008 Multiple IPv4 Addresses

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, ip

This is a bit of a strange problem that I can't seem to find a simple answer for anywhere.
We have done a clean install of Windows Server 2008 and somehow there are two IPv4 addresses assigned to the same adapter?
We have only the one adapter enabled and through the usual TCP/IP settings we have defined one IP address.

Apologies if it is a basic question, this is part of an academic course so we aren't all that experienced with it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Where are you seeing the second IP address? Both answers below are pointing to where it should be showing up, so where are you seeing indications of two addresses? Are you sure it's not something goofy with your DNS server or a cached address somewhere?

Comment: Hi, when we right click and view status -> details it displays two IP addresses. 169.254.6.184 with a subnet of 255.255.0.0 followed by our IP address and Subnet.
I can ping the 169 address from my linux box but not the other address. We cannot see anywhere that it is getting this other address from. Is there something on the DNS we can check?

Comment: Does your machine have more than one physical network port, but only one connected? It sounds almost like you have a port with a self-assigned IP because the NIC is active but the port isn't connected to a drop.

Comment: Hi, right so the network admin for the network here walked by and offered a hand.
All it took was a netsh interface reset all followed by a disable and re-enable of the adapater. Thanks for the comments / answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "usual" settings (Start, Run, ncpa.cpl, right-click adapter, Properties, TCP/IPv4, Properties), click Advanced. Multiple addresses will be listed at the top with buttons to add/edit/remove them.

EDIT:
An address of 169.* is self-assigned. It indicates that the interface is configured via DHCP and Windows has been unable to obtain an IP from the DHCP server.

If the DHCP server is up & reachable, try at the command line:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

If you're intending to set a static address, make sure the "use the follow IP address" radio button is selected in the main TCP/IPv4 properties dialog.

Comment: Hi, in there is only the one IP that we have set through the previous TCP/IP dialog (Use the following IP Address etc..). We haven't been able to find this second IP address recorded anywhere else

Comment: The 169.* is a self-assigned IP. Is the other address set by DHCP? Does the box definitely have network connectivity?

Comment: Hi, yes the the box is on the network. DHCP is disabled, but I have posted the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to where you see the one IP address assigned; there's an Advanced button at the bottom, you'll see the other IP(s) listed there, along with Add/Delete buttons.

Looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Hi, in there is only the one IP that we have set through the previous TCP/IP dialog (Use the following IP Address etc..). We haven't been able to find this second IP address recorded anywhere else